# Unity/CG: Scale object in vertex shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg

I'm trying to write a vertex shader that scales the size of the object. I've found many "solutions" to this problem, all to the tune of "expanding vertices along the normals" like so:

```
v2f vert(appdata_base v)
{
    v2f OUT;
    float3 norm = normalize(v.normal); //Unity 5 fix

    v.vertex.xyz += norm * _Scaling;
    OUT.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);

    OUT.normals = v.normal;
    return OUT;
}
```

However, this does not work for objects with sharp edges, such as cubes. In the case of a cube it just makes the sides move directly out but the sides stay the same size thus you get an "exploded" cube:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I might be missing to get any object to scale properly in the shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have the center, you also have the verticies position vector relative to that. You can find the magnitude of that and then scale that.

Comment: I'll implement this and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: For any onlookers, this method of scaling definitely doesn't work for objects that are of odd shape/concave shape.

Comment: you need to better define your requirements and also describe the problem you are having. I suspect it i a translation due to not having a correct center point. Then you run into something like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation

Comment: to better explain, the center of the model (ie minimum bounding box) and the center of say mass are not the same thing. The point around which you want to scale is very arbitrary and will be unique for any object - it just so happens that a lot of objects you describe as being convex are also typically have degrees of symetry so it cancels out. You can use the difference of those 2 vectors, scale that in the above and then use it for the translation.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, but the homothetic transformation definitely looks like what I need. Additionally, I can post an image of the result of scaling according to your original answer and my problems with it when I get home this evening. Additionally thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
float3 normal= normalize(v.vertex.xyz)*0.05;
v.vertex.xyz+= normal;
```

And disabling dynamic batching for that shader with:

```
Tags {"DisableBatching"="True"}
```

Comment: How comes that some fraggles here can edit my post?